# Add a dot instead of a comma in numberPad with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, numpad

I search how to replace a comma separator by a dot in numberPad in UITextField with Swift 5 please.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
let commaValue = textField.text!
let decimalValue = Double(commaValue.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "."))
```

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with changing the decimal separator of a number pad keyboard. What is your actual question? Do you want to actually modify the number pad (which you really shouldn't do) or do you need help properly converting a localized number string into a `Double`? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you really need help with. And be sure you clearly explain what trouble you are having with the code you posted including showing a specific example of actual input and desired output.

Comment: Hi! I search how to force decimalPad (UIKeyboadType) to change comma separator (,) to dot (.)

Comment: I’m in France and my app use the French decimalPad, so the comma separator and not the dot as I search how to force my app to use dot and not comma separator.

Comment: Why would want to force your app to use the wrong decimal separator than the user expects?

Comment: Because otherwise bug. Calculations don't work with comma separator (,), it's why I want force my app to displays a dot (.). My decimalPad (i.stack.imgur.com/9WfCU.png) and what I want for my app (i.stack.imgur.com/hriYC.png). If you can help me of course.

Comment: The proper solution is to use NumberFormatter so you can parse the entered number.

Comment: Yes, I have read this about NumberFormatter, but the problem is to implement it with my UITextField...

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to use NumberFormatter. Using a text field versus any any string is no different.

Answer (score 5):

You could use this:

```
let commaValue = "2,3"
let replaced = String(commaValue.map {
$0 == "," ? "." : $0 })
```